# ls: Display directory name when only one matches pattern

Tags: ls

When using `ls` to display files matching a pattern, it displays the directory names with contents if there are multiple matches, but if there is only one match, it omits the directory name. Here is an example:

```
example % ls
bar     barbados    foo

example % ls b*
bar:
1   2

barbados:
1   2

example % ls f*
1   2
```

In the example, requesting all files starting with `b*` matches two directories, and the output shows the names of both directories and their contents.

When I request `f*` the output shows a the single matching directory's contents, but omits the directory name.

How can I configure `ls` to display the name of the matching directory in the case that it matches only a single directory?

Comment: I can't see a way to configure `ls` to do this. In the [source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L1746) there is this: `if (n_files <= 1...) print_dir_name = false;` which sounds like it might be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Possible workaround might be a wrapper function:

```
dls() {
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ -d "$1" ]; then
        printf '%s:\n' "$1"
    fi
    ls -- "$@"
}
```

- The above function won't accept any options to be passed as arguments
- It simply checks if:

  1. there is only a single argument
  2. the argument is a directory

If those two conditions are true, print the name of the directory before listing its contents.

---

```
% dls f*
foo:
1   2
```

With some `printf` implementations, you can replace the `%s` with `%q` for the directory name to be quoted in a similar fashion as recent versions of GNU `ls` do when it contains blanks or other special characters.

Comment: I typically use an alias for `ls` anyway, so this looks promising. I’ll test it.

Comment: What's the rationale for including `--` in the invocation of `ls`?  If you drop that, then your solution would support options.  Then the limitation would be reduced to using options and listing a directory (e.g., `ls -1 f*`)

Comment: Yes, but that would make a difference only in the case where the user was listing a single directory. Seem like a better limitation than "no options ever"

Answer (score 2):

Using your examples, when you execute `ls b*`, the shell expands the `b*` into `bar barbados`, so you actually run `ls bar barbados`.  When `ls` has multiple arguments, if any of them are directories it prints the name followed by the list of files in the directory.

When you execute `ls f*`, then shell expands the `f*` into `foo`, so you actually run `ls foo`.  When `ls` has a single argument, if that argument is a directory is prints the list of files in the directory (without the directory name).

There's not what I would call a "good" way to get `ls` to do what you want (at least not that I know of, someone else might know better).  One "less than good" way would be to include an additional argument that you know would never exist, then filter the error output related to that nonexistent file.  I'll note for the record that parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea, but I'll give you this in case it helps:

```bsh
$ function dls() {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        ls
    else
        ls ${@} this-file-does-not-exist-anywhere 2> >(grep -v this-file-does-not-exist-anywhere)
    fi
}

$ dls
foo

$ dls f*
foo:
1  2
```

Doing something like this might have unintended consequences (e.g., you might not be able to redirect standard error messages like you normally would).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the expansion information. While I’m not sure about your proposed solution, I found the description about the expansion process very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-al` parameter, which most ppl use everytime. `ls` wont do it then, until you add a trailing slash to the dirname. The other parameter is `-d`, it won't descend in any way, then.

If you want it permanent, put the following into your `.bashrc` within your home directory:

```
alias lsd='ls -d' ;
```

You can use the command `lsd` in future.

Comment: I suspect you misinterpreted the question. The OP wants the `dirname:` header to be prepended to every directory listing even if `ls` is passed only one argument. `ls -d` won't help at all here.

Comment: Indeed. Never recognized it as problem, anyway. :)